# No of people present at given hour of day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a query which lists number of people present during a given hour of day in a 24 hour open store. Here is the eg table

```
Customer_ID    ENTRYDATETIME              EXITDATETIME
-----------------------------------------------------------------    
1001           2017-01-01 09:06:35.477    2017-01-01 12:06:35.477
1001           2017-01-05 11:06:35.477    2017-01-05 17:05:00.000
1002           2017-01-01 14:06:35.477    2017-01-01 19:05:00.000
1003           2017-01-01 14:06:35.477    2017-01-01 20:05:00.000
1067           2017-01-01 14:06:35.477    2017-01-01 16:05:00.000
1067           2017-01-02 14:06:35.477    2017-01-01 15:05:00.000
1067           2017-01-03 14:06:35.477    2017-01-01 16:05:00.000
1091           2017-01-10 14:06:35.477    2017-01-01 18:05:00.000
```

So here you see that customer 1001 was present on 1stJAN at 9AM, 10AM, 11AM, 12PM

Likewise, customer #1002 was present on 1stJAN at 11AM, 12,13,14,1500.

At the end of the month I would want to see the average number of customers present in the store at hour of day. or even averaged out for day of month etc.

Can someone please logic this out for me. You time and effort is much appreciated.

Comment: edit the question add ur expected output.

Comment: The last 2 lines with Customer_ID 1067, 1091 have EXITDATETIME that occur before ENTRYDATETIME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (Customer_ID INT, ENTRYDATETIME DATETIME, EXITDATETIME DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES

(1001,'2017-01-01 09:06:35.477','2017-01-01 12:06:35.477'),
(1001,'2017-01-05 11:06:35.477','2017-01-05 17:05:00.000'),
(1002,'2017-01-01 14:06:35.477','2017-01-01 19:05:00.000'),
(1003,'2017-01-01 14:06:35.477','2017-01-01 20:05:00.000'),
(1067,'2017-01-01 14:06:35.477','2017-01-01 16:05:00.000'),
(1067,'2017-01-02 14:06:35.477','2017-01-02 15:05:00.000'),
(1067,'2017-01-03 14:06:35.477','2017-01-03 16:05:00.000'),
(1091,'2017-01-10 14:06:35.477','2017-01-10 18:05:00.000')

;WITH CTE as
(
    select Customer_ID, CAST(ENTRYDATETIME AS DATE) ENTRYDATE, DATEPART(HOUR, ENTRYDATETIME) ENTRYHOUR from @Temp
    UNION all
    select CTE.Customer_ID, CAST(ENTRYDATETIME AS DATE) DT,  ENTRYHOUR = ENTRYHOUR + 1  from @Temp T INNER JOIN CTE ON T.Customer_ID = CTE.Customer_ID 
        AND ENTRYDATE = CAST(ENTRYDATETIME AS DATE)
        AND (ENTRYHOUR + 1) <= DATEPART(HOUR, EXITDATETIME)
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
order by Customer_ID, ENTRYDATE, ENTRYHOUR
```

**Second method:** Instead of recursive CTE, I used a cross join with a timetable. Probably works faster than the first approach.

```
;WITH HourTable AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23)) Hhr (HourIndex)
)
SELECT 
    T.Customer_ID, 
    CAST(T.ENTRYDATETIME AS DATE) ENTRYDATE, DATEPART(HOUR, DATEADD(HOUR, H.HourIndex, T.ENTRYDATETIME)) ENTRYHOUR 
FROM @Temp T
    INNER JOIN HourTable H ON DATEDIFF( HOUR, T.ENTRYDATETIME, T.EXITDATETIME ) >= H.HourIndex
ORDER BY 
    Customer_ID, 
    ENTRYDATE, 
    ENTRYHOUR
```

Result:

```
Customer_ID ENTRYDATE  ENTRYHOUR
----------- ---------- -----------
1001        2017-01-01 9
1001        2017-01-01 10
1001        2017-01-01 11
1001        2017-01-01 12
1001        2017-01-05 11
1001        2017-01-05 12
1001        2017-01-05 13
1001        2017-01-05 14
1001        2017-01-05 15
1001        2017-01-05 16
1001        2017-01-05 17
1002        2017-01-01 14
1002        2017-01-01 15
1002        2017-01-01 16
1002        2017-01-01 17
1002        2017-01-01 18
1002        2017-01-01 19
1003        2017-01-01 14
1003        2017-01-01 15
1003        2017-01-01 16
1003        2017-01-01 17
1003        2017-01-01 18
1003        2017-01-01 19
1003        2017-01-01 20
1067        2017-01-01 14
1067        2017-01-01 15
1067        2017-01-01 16
1067        2017-01-02 14
1067        2017-01-02 15
1067        2017-01-03 14
1067        2017-01-03 15
1067        2017-01-03 16
1091        2017-01-10 14
1091        2017-01-10 15
1091        2017-01-10 16
1091        2017-01-10 17
1091        2017-01-10 18
```

And this if for the avarage by hour.

```
;WITH CTE as
(
    select Customer_ID, CAST(ENTRYDATETIME AS DATE) ENTRYDATE, DATEPART(HOUR, ENTRYDATETIME) ENTRYHOUR from @Temp
    UNION all
    select CTE.Customer_ID, CAST(ENTRYDATETIME AS DATE) DT,  ENTRYHOUR = ENTRYHOUR + 1  from @Temp T INNER JOIN CTE ON T.Customer_ID = CTE.Customer_ID 
        AND ENTRYDATE = CAST(ENTRYDATETIME AS DATE)
        AND (ENTRYHOUR + 1) <= DATEPART(HOUR, EXITDATETIME)
)
SELECT ENTRYHOUR, COUNT(*) AVARAGE FROM CTE
GROUP BY ENTRYHOUR
```

Result:

```
ENTRYHOUR   AVARAGE
----------- -----------
9           1
10          1
11          2
12          2
13          1
14          7
15          7
16          6
17          4
18          3
19          2
20          1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have more than 200K rows of data and the execution time of this query is very long, more than 30mins and still running.

Comment: I added a second solution to my answer, probably it works faster.

Comment: Using a Cross join with Date time table worked., initially took long. However when NONCLUSTERED INDEX on the table to INCLUDE entry time and exit time was used,  it worked smooth. I did this few days ago and the code is hidden itself in one of the many jobs I had completed. i will share the code after I get the correct folder this code has been saved into. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend generating a `date / time` table (either using a `CTE` or as a static table) then joining to that table on '`BETWEEN`' `EntryDateTime` and `ExitDateTime`.